# How to use class/function in another swift file which in same folder without Xcode

Tags: swift

I write protocol and classes in G.swift, and write functions and tests in L.swift. These two files in same folder, and I need "import" G.someclass in L.swift.

I searched on internet and it said I do not need import command if two files in same directory. But I am not using Xcode to write these file. I just want write lite function, and run them like Python or Go.

Could it happen? Or I have to use Xcode to make "import" operation happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not using xcode, I assume you're running them either via `swift` or `swiftc`. In either case, just list both files on the command line and they will be treated as the same module. Your `L.swift` file should have a `main()` function that runs the tests.